# Twilio ml <play> mp4

Tags: twilio

I am using `Twilio ML <play>` to play audio over the phone. I manage to play the audio when the file type is mp3.

Due to some constraints we change the file type to mp4  which I read is accepted by Twilio. (accepted mime types)

When I tested the process I got an error when I tried to play an mp4 files. The logs in my Twilio account shows the following error code:

```
"12300 Invalid Content-Type"
```

I was googling  this error code and  found that this error can occurred when the content type is not sent by the server , so I checked the headers using fiddler and it seems fine to me: `(Content-Type: video/mp4)`

I will appreciate any advise with this issue.

Comment: mp4 is video, mp4a is audio. Twilio won't let you use an mp4 to play only audio.

Comment: mp4 can also be used for audio without video.

Comment: sure it can, the question is:  does Twilio allow that ?

Comment: Why don't you create a support ticket with Twilio and ask them?

Comment: I did, when they did not answer for two days I posed here. Their answer is: Twilio does not support mp4 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio only supports the following audio formats:

MIME TYPE   DESCRIPTION

- audio/mpeg   mpeg layer 3 audio
- audio/wav    wav format audio
- audio/wave  wav format audio audio/x-wav    wav format audio
- audio/aiff   audio interchange file format audio/x-aifc  audio
- interchange file format audio/x-aiff    audio interchange file format
- audio/x-gsm GSM audio format audio/gsm  GSM audio format
- audio/ulaw  μ-law audio format

  See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play for more details